# ExceptionHandler not working with Spring Cloud and Aws Lambda

Tags: java, spring-boot, aws-lambda, spring-cloud, serverless

I created a function on AWS Lambda with Spring Cloud and java 11.
I'm trying to catch the exceptions thrown with @ExceptionHandler but it's not working.

I'm using an API Gateway Http Api as a trigger

Is there any specific way to catch these exceptions with Spring Cloud?

Function

```
@Component
public class TestFunction implements Function<APIGatewayV2HTTPEvent, APIGatewayV2HTTPResponse> {

    @Override
    public APIGatewayV2HTTPResponse apply(APIGatewayV2HTTPEvent event) {

        throw new TestException();

    }
}
```

Handle

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class TestExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = {TestException.class})
    public APIGatewayV2HTTPResponse handleTestException(TestException e) {
        return APIGatewayV2HTTPResponse.builder()
                .withStatusCode(422).build();
    }
}
```

Handle - second attempt as suggested by @kladderradatsch

```
@ControllerAdvice(basePackageClasses = TestFunction.class)
public class TestExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ResponseBody
    @ExceptionHandler(value = {TestException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleTestException(TestException ex) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new MyErrorBody(400, ex.getMessage()), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Exception

```
public class TestException extends RuntimeException {
    public TestException() {
        super("Error Test.");
    }
}
```

I tried to catch the exception in several different ways, including adding a @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST) to the exception, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Your handler is not correct, please [take a closer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.5/reference/htmlsingle/#web.servlet.spring-mvc.error-handling) look how a ControllerAdvice handler must be implemented.

Comment: @kladderradatsch Thank you so much for your answer. I made the tweak in the code as per the Spring documentation, but that didn't work either. Regardless of the error, it always returns a 500 error. I tried some variations based on the documentation and it didn't work. The function is working correctly.

Comment: Please show us your last adjustments in the code above.

Comment: @kladderradatsch I added your suggestion in the examples above, is that ok?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know why it's not working. I am not experienced in AWS-Lambda.